# Link .txt file to LaTeX

Tags: texmaker, links

I'm wondering if there are any packages/add-ons/programs that can link a `.txt` file (or some simple text file) to a `.tex` document.

So this is what I'm looking for. I have a LaTeX document like this:

```
\begin{document}
First number: ${REF1}$

Second number: ${REF2}$
\end{document}
```

And a `.txt` document like this:

```
REF1 = 123
REF2 = 221
```

And the `REF#` gets replaced by the number automatically, and updated if the `.txt` file is modified.

(P.S. I'm using Texmaker)

Answer (score 3):

You can load the file and interpret each line as a key-value pair.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.txt}
REF1 = 123
REF2 = 221
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\loadkeyfile}{m}
 {
  \tl_gset_from_file:Nnn \g__razero_input_tl
   { \endlinechar=`, }
   { #1 }
  \keys_set:nV { razero/keyfile } \g__razero_input_tl
 }
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\usekey}{m}
 {
  \tl_use:c { g_razero_key_#1_tl }
 }

\tl_new:N \g__razero_input_tl
\keys_define:nn { razero/keyfile }
 {
  unknown .code:n = \tl_new:c { g_razero_key_ \l_keys_key_tl _tl }
                    \tl_gset:cn { g_razero_key_ \l_keys_key_tl _tl } { #1 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \keys_set:nn { nV }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\loadkeyfile{\jobname.txt}

\begin{document}

--First number: \usekey{REF1}--

--Second number: \usekey{REF2}--

\end{document}
```

The `filecontents*` environment is just to make the example self-contained. In the argument to `\loadkeyfile` use your file name.

The dashes are just to show that no unwanted space has been introduced.

[image]

An alternative definition that scans the input file line by line.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.txt}
REF1 = 123
REF2 = 221
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\loadkeyfile}{m}
 {
  \ior_open:Nn \g__razero_input_stream { #1 }
  \ior_map_inline:Nn \g__razero_input_stream
   {
    \keys_set:nn { razero/keyfile } { ##1 }
   }
 }
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\usekey}{m}
 {
  \tl_use:c { g_razero_key_#1_tl }
 }

\ior_new:N \g__razero_input_stream
\keys_define:nn { razero/keyfile }
 {
  unknown .code:n = \tl_new:c { g_razero_key_ \l_keys_key_tl _tl }
                    \tl_gset:cn { g_razero_key_ \l_keys_key_tl _tl } { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\loadkeyfile{\jobname.txt}

\begin{document}

--First number: \usekey{REF1}--

--Second number: \usekey{REF2}--

\end{document}
```